# Google Ads Script - Pause multiple campaigns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I'm getting to Google Ads scripts. I managed to execute this script that pauses a specific campaign but I couldn't apply this to multiple campaigns. Here is what I tried, but it only pauses the first campaign in ("Name IN ['**test1**', 'test2']"). Could someone help me to achieve this?

```js
function main () {
  var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
    .withCondition("Name IN ['test1', 'test2']").get();
  if (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
    campaign.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have a trigger for the campaign to resume?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change from if to while as in the example below to iterate through all campaigns.

```js
function main () {
  var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
    .withCondition("Name IN ['test1', 'test2']").get();
  while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
    campaign.pause();
  }
}
```